# Migration from componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs and I wrote component with the method componentWillReceiveProps (cWRP) but I read that it is deprecated and it must replace with getDerivedStateFromProps (gDSFP) - https://en.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html.
Please note that the following code has the sole purpose of illustrating my problem and questions. It is not a full code.
App.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Display from './component.js'

class App extends React.Component {

  state={resetCounter:false}

  resetCounter= () => this.setState( {resetCounter: true} );

  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Display resetCounter={this.state.resetCounter}></Display>
          <div>
           <p></p><p></p>
           <button onClick={this.resetCounter}>Reset</button>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    if (this.state.resetCounter!==false)
      this.setState( {resetCounter: false} );
  }

}

export default App;
```

component.js file

```
import React from 'react'

class Display extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = this.resetState();
    this.state.generalCounter=0;
  } 

  /* method to avoid code duplication in constructor and cWRP
   could not be used with getDerivedStateFromProps */
  resetState = () => ({resettableCounter: 0,}); 

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.resetCounter===true) 
      this.setState(this.resetState())
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
        <div>
        <div>general counter : {this.state.generalCounter}</div>
        <div>resettable counter : {this.state.resettableCounter}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.incCounters}>+</button>
            <button onClick={this.decCounters}>-</button>
        </div>
        </>
    )
  }

  incCounters= () => this.setState(
    {
      resettableCounter: this.state.resettableCounter+1,
      generalCounter: this.state.generalCounter+1 
    }
  )

  decCounters= () => this.setState(
    {
      resettableCounter: this.state.resettableCounter-1,
      generalCounter: this.state.generalCounter-1
    }
  )

}

export default Display
```

In the state of the component, there is a resettable part and a non resettable one. A method `resetState` is used to avoid code duplication in the constructor and in cWRP.
To replace cWRP by gDSFP, I wrote a class method because instance method could NOT be called in gDSFP (`this` is not usable)

```
... 

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = Display.resetState();
    this.state.generalCounter=0;
  } 

  static resetState () {
    return ({resettableCounter: 0,}); 
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.resetCounter === true) {
      return Display.resetState();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

...
```

With this solution, it is very easy to modify all my components but I am not sure that it is a good mean.
I wonder if I have a misconception and if I should rewrite my components to separate them into Fully controlled components and Fully uncontrolled components with a key ( https://en.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions). 
For example, in this case, do I have to write :

1. One Fully uncontrolled components for the resettable counter
2. One Fully controlled one for the non resettable counter
3. A parent component with the +/- buttons to render them.

I ask this question because in some cases, it will be much work, so I want to be sure before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to keep the `gdsfp` version in your post if your component depends on some outside props, which you don't have controll over (such as JSON returned or 3rd party render props component, etc).

It looks like you have a full control over what's passed down to the `Display`. You can pass down an initial `resettableCounter` value down to `Display`.

The advantage is two-folds.

1. Your `Display` props shows what the `Display` does - Making it more descriptivie/readable.
2. It's easier to maintain, as you don't have to massage the data.

For your particular case, `Fully uncontrolled component with a key` seems to make more sense, as `Display` should accept the initial value to show, but is responsible for managing the `reseetableCounter`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's absolutely unavoidable, don't create components which control their siblings (or parents). Instead, lift state to a common ancestor:

```
const Display = ({
  generalCounter,
  resettableCounter,
  incrementCounters,
  decrementCounters,
}) => (
  <div>
    <div>General Counter: {generalCounter}</div>
    <div>Resettable Counter: {resettableCounter}</div>
    <button onClick={incrementCounters}>Increment</button>
    <button onClick={decrementCounters}>Decrement</button>
  </div>
);

class DisplayContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    generalCounter: 0,
    resettableCounter: 0,
  };

  incrementCounters = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
    generalCounter: prevState.generalCounter + 1,
    resettableCounter: prevState.resettableCounter + 1,
  }));

  decrementCounters = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
    generalCounter: prevState.generalCounter - 1,
    resettableCounter: prevState.resettableCounter - 1,
  }));

  resetResettableCounter = () => this.setState({
    resettableCounter: 0,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Display
          {...this.state}
          incrementCounters={this.incrementCounters}
          decrementCounters={this.decrementCounters}
        />
        <button onClick={this.resetResettableCounter}>
          Reset Resettable Counter
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <DisplayContainer />
  </div>
);
```

An alternative approach would be something like Redux (which effectively lifts state out of React).